# How can i fix the error Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin, django-static, django-upgrade

After changing my python and Django version I came up with the error of
 `Uncaught ReferenceError: addEvent is not defined`.

The error took place at my `DateTimeShortcuts.js` file.

The code raising the error is:

```
addEvent(window, 'load', DateTimeShortcuts.init);
window.DateTimeShortcuts = DateTimeShortcuts;
```

This error prevents me for rendering correct a date widget that I am using for my Django app.

Any idea how to handle it?

Comment: Make sure that whatever script defines `addEvent` is included **before** the above script

Comment: @gtopal posted answer, let me know if that works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60855051/3722635

Comment: @wowkin2 There were changes in the file , like you said.

Comment: @gtopal, the main question from me: was the running command enough or you did any other steps?

Comment: @wowkin2 it was the running command enough. Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From commit into Django framework "[Fixed #28536 -- Removed old JS cross-browser utilities](https://github.com/django/django/commit/afc06b56256f78ab832ff8066ac6f34b7443de22#diff-cb2d960617da7bad9ba5ed3366931159)" you can see that there were changes in that file.

Try to run [command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic) that will refresh all static files:

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is '**addEvent**' is not defined previously.

Make sure that you have the definition of '**addEvent**' imported or written before this line.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should write

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ...
```